# Delete duplicate record which isn't pointed to by another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables in my DB:

```
table_1:
id: primary key (sequential)
A: date
B: uuid

table_2:
table_1_id: foreign key to Table 1
```

table_1 has duplicate entries in the A and B columns that I would like to delete, but one of those entries is pointed to by the foreign key in table_2.  I want to delete the entry that *isn't* pointed to by said foreign key.

Any recommendations?  (I'm trying to add a unique index on table_1 on columns (A,B), but I can't because of these duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
delete from table_1 t1
    using (select a, b, count(*) as cnt
           from table_1
           group by a, b
          ) tt1
    where tt1.a = t1.a and tt1.b = t1.b and tt1.cnt > 1 and
          not exists (select 1
                      from table_2 t2
                      where t2.table_1_id = t1.id
                     );
```

This will keep singleton values that have no foreign key reference.  Note:  If there are duplicates and none are referenced, they will be deleted.  That seems to be what you are asking for.

EDIT:

I am guessing that you really want to do the following:

- Delete all non-referenced rows in `table_1`
- EXCEPT for `a`/`b` values that have no references.  In that case, keep one of them.

If so:

```
delete from table_1 t1
    from (select tt1.*,
                 count(*) filter (where in_tt2) as num_in_tt2,
                 row_number() over (partition by a, b order by id) as seqnum
          from (select tt1.*, 
                       (exists (select 1 from tt2 where tt2.table_1_id = tt1.id)) as in_tt2
                from table_1 tt1 
               ) tt1
         ) tt1
    where tt1.id = t1.id and
          (not tt1.in_tt2 and num_in_tt2 = 0 and seqnum > 1);
```

Comment: The first one is what I want.  How do I look at the values first?

Comment: Replace the `delete` with `select`, change the `using` to `join` and you basically have a `select` statement with the rows to delete.

Comment: Gordon Linoff In the Second SQL you haven;t used `table_2` anywhere. So is it a mistake? can you amend it or post it again